# angular-cli for webpack does not really work

Tags: angular-cli

I'm using "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2"

my angular-cli-build.js I have:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    ]
  });
};
```

and my index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

but with ng build, i get nothing in /dist folder... how this does work exactly with webpack? I used to work easy with webpack and angular 1, now i see it's really complicated and i wasting a lot of time trying to guess how that must work, and i see angular-cli is just for test, not for real work? there is a way to replace angular-cli compile to override it with webpack in the old way?

Comment: my advice, it's not use angular-cli for real work or simple app , you can spend a lot of days and hours simply trying install. version that don't use webpack is not professional and very unstable, so for real production better look for a starter and do the things manually, you will save a lot of hours and days like I had to do.

Comment: version for Web pack is  dark, you are prisoner, things and config is inside the core and not in a simple Web pack config, you are prisoner of beta versions and decisions of programmers , i'm not going to use it at least for this year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3` or higher, you can use the `apps[0].styles` property of `angular-cli.json` to list external stylesheets for import. With this you don't have to add anything to `index.html`.

To upgrade from `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2`, run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3
```

From https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli, the additional steps to run in your project directory when upgrading an existing project are:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
ng init
```

If you generate a new project and install Bootstrap, your `angular-cli.json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3",
    "name": "demo"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}
```

Comment: Different guy, same problem -- I tried upgrading to `webpack.3` and it didn't fix my issue of loading global styles. I updated my `angular-cli.json` file to look like what you show as well. Are there other files that need changes? Or should I just start over with a new project and copy my existing code over? Thanks in advance!

Comment: doing your advise i get with npm install : ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.0.2
└── zone.js@0.6.12 

npm WARN string-replace-loader@1.0.3 requires a peer of webpack@1.x.x || 2.x.x but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.5.0 requires a peer of typescript@^1.9.0-dev but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@^2.0.0-rc.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.2.2 requires a peer of typescript@^1.9.0-dev but none was installed.
etc

Comment: and then with : ng serve,  i get just an "Error" in red, and nothing more; my environment: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8
node: 6.5.0
os: darwin x64

Comment: @TheManiac to upgrade an existing project see the steps here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: @stackdave do you get the same problem if you try with 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3? I had problems with 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8 also and found 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3 better. As mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#install-packages) the app should still run even if you get `npm WARN` during install.

Comment: thanks @MarkLeong, but I've realised after a lot of days, than  angular-cli , it's not ready for real production, just to play with some commands, you can spend a lot of days trying resolve simple things; so it's better i ll do the things manually , It's sad but  is one of the more unstable packages that I've used. I repeat i don't advise people use angular-cli in this year for real productions.

Comment: Thanks @MarkLeong, but should `npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest` instead use the webpack build, i.e. `npm install --save-dev angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3`? Although I'm getting tons of errors when I try to `ng build` so maybe not!

Comment: @TheManiac `angular-cli@latest` will give you `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` at the moment. You can run `npm dist-tag ls angular-cli` to see what the current `@latest` distribution tag points to.

Comment: @MarkLeong Hmm it definitely installed broccoli instead of webpack, and `npm dist-tag ls angular-cli` shows "latest" as "1.0.0-beta.10" -- which if I'm understanding correctly is not webpack. Again, thanks for all your help!

Comment: @TheManiac you're right, my bad! `angular-cli@latest` gives you `1.0.0-beta.10`, which **isn't** the webpack one. `angular-cli@webpack` gives you `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` (the latest webpack version), which I found more buggy than `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3` hence my the version recommended in my answer.

Comment: @MarkLeong So I've tried `@webpack`, and `@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3` and both are giving me hundreds of `Cannot find name '[something]'` errors in the core of Angular (i.e. `Cannot find name 'Function'` and even "Object" is throwing errors). I feel like something is wrong with typings, but am not knowledgeable enough to know where to look... any more advice? Thanks either way!

Comment: @TheManiac it sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1901) with typscript 2.0.2. Changing changing `"typescript": "^2.0.0"` to `"typescript": "2.0.0"` in `package.json` and running `npm install` fixed it for me.

Comment: @MarkLeong Ah man how did I not find that with my searching -- that was it! You've been a huge help, I wish I could buy you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that work with angular-cli is very unstable, it's better to use a webstarte and do the things manually , angular 2 release candidate is changing yet this year and the things are slow, worst for angular-cli

https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack

Steps to work with bootstrap4 css:

```
1. npm install --save bootstrap@^4.0.0-alpha.3
2. in app.component.ts just insert:

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

and everything is magic and working:

everything is automatic and have no problems like with angular-cli, i don't advice use this last to build the app, just to generate componentes or thinks like that; angular-cli is really very beta state development.

Comment: Anyone who comes across this in the future, we should state that the angular-cli has come a long way and is now also the "recommended" tool to use during angular development. To answer the original question you can add assets in your angular directly into your angular-cli.json config file. Have a look at the default one when you type in ng new [project name] for a clean example.